# How to edit several elements in df.columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For example, the elements of the columns is `['a', 'b', 2006.0, 2005.0, ... ,1995.0]`

Now, I hope to change the float to int, so the correct elements of the columns should be `['a', 'b', 2006, 2005, ... , 1995]`

Since there are many numbers here, I don't think `rename(columns={'old name': 'new name'})` is a good idea. Can anyone tell me how to edit it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this:

```
In [49]: df
Out[49]:
   a  b  2006.0  2005.0
0  1  1       1       1
1  2  2       2       2

In [50]: df.columns.tolist()
Out[50]: ['a', 'b', 2006.0, 2005.0]

In [51]: df.rename(columns=lambda x: int(x) if type(x) == float else x)
Out[51]:
   a  b  2006  2005
0  1  1     1     1
1  2  2     2     2
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use `list comprehension`:

```
print (df.columns.tolist())
['a', 'b', 2006.0, 2005.0, 1995.0]

print ([int(col) if type(col) == float else col for col in df.columns])
['a', 'b', 2006, 2005, 1995]

df.columns =  [int(col) if type(col) == float else col for col in df.columns]
['a', 'b', 2006, 2005, 1995]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!